Get codepage for underlying terminal on POSIX systems in C
I'm working on a own libc implementation for the purpose of education. Now I want support none-ANSI characters output. For the implementation from wprintf as example I want check the underlying terminal codepage first and convert the wprintf input into this copepage. wchar_t to UTF-8 as example, depending on the terminal settings.
The background, on major libc implementations like Glibc, mixing from printf and wprintf isn't possible. When I use both of the *printf variants, only the first output works. The second call with the another function call, will be discarded. Unfortunately, I don't know the real reason. Also when I use wprintf only, without setlocale(LC_ALL, "") the corresponding character will not be displayed (there will displayed a question mark). In my implementation I want to deal with it, as described in the introductory text, because AFAIK in the C specification this behavior is undefined.
I know there exists the environment variable LANG, which I could parse first. On Windows there exist GetConsoleCP() function. Is there an equivalent function on POSIX systems, instead for parsing the environment variables?

File streams are initially unoriented.  If you first write to a stream with a byte-oriented function such as printf(), it becomes byte-oriented and the wide character functions will all fail.  Conversely, if you first write to a stream with a wide-oriented function such as wprintf(), it becomes wide-oriented and byte-oriented functions fail.  Look up fwide() and read the introductory sections of the standard for the <stdio.h> header.

because AFAIK in the C specification this behavior is undefined. to which behavior are you referring to exactly? to when I use wprintf only, without setlocale(LC_ALL, "") the corresponding character will not be displayed or to When I use both of the *printf variants, only the first output works?

1. Locale Concepts
A locale defines regional settings such as:

Character Encoding: e.g., UTF-8, ISO-8859-1.
Date and Time Formats.
Number Formats.
Currency Symbols.
Collation Rules (String Sorting).

Locale Categories
POSIX defines the following locale categories:



Category
Purpose




LC_CTYPE
Character classification and case conversion.


LC_NUMERIC
Numeric formatting (decimal points, grouping).


LC_TIME
Date and time formatting.


LC_COLLATE
String collation (sorting).


LC_MONETARY
Currency formatting.


LC_MESSAGES
Localized messages and prompts.


LC_ALL
Applies to all categories.



2. Environment Variables
Locales in Linux are set using environment variables:

LANG: Specifies the default locale for all categories.
LC_ALL: Overrides all other locale settings.
LC_CTYPE, LC_NUMERIC, etc.: Set specific categories.

So you need to read the env variables in your library

Thanks for the answer first. I may have misspoken my question. I must admit, in my current libc implementation , I haven't implementsetlocale and/or nl_langinfo. So the question is: Is there a POSIX way to determine these information only with syscalls?

@JohannesKrottmayer I don't think locale is a kernel feature, it's a user-mode library feature, so there are no system calls related to it.


from wprintf as example I want check the underlying terminal codepage first and convert the wprintf input into this copepage

No, no, no, wprintf converts depending on LC_CTYPE. The code has to work depending on LC_CTYPE, irrelevant if it is connected to a terminal at all or to how many terminals it is connected to. Terminals do not matter. Moreover, you can convert between different multibyte encodings using LC_CTYPEs. This all is irrelevant to the terminal.
All you care about is LC_CTYPE locale. Your code should convert from wide strings to multibyte characters using whatever is specified in LC_CTYPE and output it, irrelevant of any terminals existence.

when I use wprintf only, without setlocale(LC_ALL, "") the corresponding character will not be displayed

Yes, because by default LC_TYPE=C, so no wide characters and no unicode.

because AFAIK in the C specification this behavior is undefined.

The default LC_CTYPE on program startup is C, https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.11.1.1p4 . I do not think you can make C locale encoding UTF-8 - I believe that would conflict with sorting.

I know there exists the environment variable LANG

LANG is for the language. This is unrelated to encoding. You can write a Polish or a German message in UTF-8 or UTF-16. Same message, different language, different encodings.
And locale is not an environment variable. Empty string call setlocale(LC_ALL, "") is equal to setlocale(LC_ALL, getenv("LC_ALL")), but otherwise environment variables are not used at all.

On Windows there exist GetConsoleCP() function

Yes, I think windows has one old terminal-ish interface.

Is there an equivalent function on POSIX systems, instead for parsing the environment variables?

No. On Linux anything is a terminal, and it is impossible to know what terminal supports. You can connect a terminals half-duplex write-only, it is impossible to ask the terminal what encodings it supports.
Bottom line:

I want check the underlying terminal codepage first and convert the wprintf input into this copepage

Yes - so write a function that initialized LC_CTYPE locale from GetConsoleCP() output. You can be non-portable and execute setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "") on program startup (but: error handling, segfaults, will be very suprising to users). This all is unrelated to wprintf implementation.
